# Should Loop be used if the source data is always changing? OR is there a better method?

Tags: vba, excel

So in sheet 1 i have lets say formulas from cell B2 to E6 f(CN#) that is dependent on the values in A2 to A6, lets call them customer numbers (CN#).see picture below.
 these customer numbers would be the same for all the formulas in columns next to it so the whole range is A1-E5 These lines of formulas can increase or decrease monthly so it could be in any given month A1-E5 or A1-E8 or A1-E3.
My problem is that i need to copy and paste these ranges one after another and change the customer numbers or CN# each time a new range is posted.  These CN# are located on sheet2

Sorry for the bad grammar but this thing is kicking my butt

Edit:
the formulas f(CN#) are all different.  I guess i should explain what i am doing currently.
I take A2-E5 and copy it down to A6-E11.  I then change the Value CN1 to CN2.  wash rinse and repeat till i get to my last CN#.
If the number lines and columns were static that was an easy fix, but they are not and they change monthly.
The issue is repeating the formulas (B2toE6) which varies then copying them.  lets call that a set.  so i'd need a set for each customer number.  i was thinking of using a dynamic range like

Range(Cells(1,2),Cells(1,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Select

but im lost from that point forward.

[image]

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more information about the formula. As you explain it now, it seems like you could just write one formula and have it reference the cell in the A column (and then drag the formula across and down)

Comment: ahhh good point.  each formula is different but that really isn't the issue.  The issue is recreating the ranges without me having to change CN1 to CN2 and then to CN3 and on and on each time.  But thank you i will make this clearer in the edit.

Comment: Instead of hard-coding the CN# you should pass in the CN# cell as a parameter.  ie `=f(A2)` instead of `=f(CN1)`.  Then as you fill down it will automatically adjust that cell reference.

Comment: So you write the customer number in everytime..So for cell B2, you fill in CN1 individually rather than referencing cell A1?

Comment: No i reference the cell above when the CN is the same.  I'd have to change it when the new set begins or A6.

Comment: You're going to need to be more explicit in your question if the current comments/answers don't address your problem. `each formula is different but that really isn't the issue` - seems like this may be *exactly* the issue, but you don't explain how they are different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to have a helper cell somewhere: something that tells excel how many times to repeat - this will mean changing a single cell, rather than trying to work things out for multiple cells.

I made a couple of assumptions, which should be relatively easy to modify.

1. Your list you want to make starts at **A2**
2. Your list of customers starts at **Sheet2!A2**
3. Your helper cell is at **B1**

Your formula, starting in A4 and running down would be:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$2,INT(ROW()-ROW($A$2))/$B$1,0)
```

The list will start producing `0` when you run out of customers. If you wanted to be tidy, you could wrap the function in an IF statement

```
=IF(OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$2,INT(ROW()-ROW($A$2))/$B$1,0)=0,"",OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$2,INT(ROW()-ROW($A$2))/$B$1,0))
```

Or you could use conditional formatting to set the cell color and the font color to be the same to make it "hidden"

Comment: The issue is repeating the formulas (B2toE6) which varies in length then copying them.  lets call that a set.  so i'd need a set for each customer number.  i was thinking of using a dynamic range like

Range(Cells(1,2),Cells(1,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Select

but im lost from that point forward.